# Camel case to lowercase first character regex

Tags: javascript, regex, camelcasing

I'm trying to rename a certain type of strings with `.replace()` and REGEX.

- `myCustomClass` -> `customClass`
- `myCustomOption` -> `customOption`

I need something that in effect does this `string.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + string.slice(1)`, but with REGEX.

So I'm working on something like this

```js
var myCustomClass = 'myCustomClass',
    myCustomOption = 'myCustomOption';
    
document.body.innerHTML = myCustomClass.replace('my','')
                         .replace(/([A-Z])/, ('$1').toLowerCase() ) + '<br>'

document.body.innerHTML += myCustomOption.replace('my','')
                          .replace(/([A-Z])/, ('$1').toLowerCase() )
```

The results are `CustomClass` and `CustomOption`, which is not what I was expecting. How can I do this please?

Comment: Use a function as second parameter to replace. All you are doing is `.replace(/[A_Z])/, '$1' /* result of toLowerCase call */)` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: Let me update the post real quick.

Comment: Thanks @ASDFGerte I posted an answer, hope it helps others, you're the man.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, this is the solution:

`string.replace(/[A-Z]/, (match) => match.toLowerCase() )`

Demo:

```js
var myCustomClass = 'myCustomClass',
    myCustomOption = 'myCustomOption';
    
document.body.innerHTML = myCustomClass.replace('my','')
                         .replace(/[A-Z]/, (match) => match.toLowerCase() ) + '<br>'

document.body.innerHTML += myCustomOption.replace('my','')
                          .replace(/[A-Z]/, (match) => match.toLowerCase() )
```